# GCE Instance IP Address

Tags: google-compute-engine

I recently created a GCE instance in the "europe-west" zone.
Its intended to run an application that connects off to an external webservice.
When trying to login to the webservice I get an error about restricted region.
It turns out the webservice does not accept login requests from US regions.
I checked and even though my instance is in the "europe-west" zone, its associated IP is being reported as US.
Is there anything I can do to get a proper region IP or is there any way around this?
May need to abandon GCE if the answer is no...

Thanks
Robert

Comment: Look at this last [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/RjzyHRBRujg) in this 'gce-discussion' thread for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reposting the [answer from Gary Ling](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/gce-discussion/RjzyHRBRujg), product manager for external networking:

> Thank you for posting the email. We are aware of this issue that
>   (almost) all Google IP addresses are SWIP'ed to be Mountain View, CA.
>   And at Google, it's not uncommon to remap a block of IPs from one
>   location to another, especially given the elasticity of IP addresses
>   for the Cloud. Too bad that many of external Geo IP services solely
>   depend on SWIP database. While we are evaluating what we can do to
>   help our customers, your best bet in my opinion is contacting your
>   API provider and explore options they may offer now.

To be more explicit, there are several ways that a Geo IP provider might determine the location of an IP address.  Most of these probably won't work well with a global cloud provider like GCP.

1. Associate the IP with the region of the allocating internet authority.  In this case, GCE has addresses mostly allocated from ARIN, the American Internet authority.  Once allocated to Google, these addresses can be used in any location by managing routing rules on Google's internal network.
2. Associate the IP with the address of the registering company.  In that case, the official address associated with all GCP IPs is the Google Mountain View headquarters, even for addresses used in Europe or Asia.
3. Use network distance measurements to determine where a subnet is located.   This method is more expensive, because it requires sending active pings from multiple locations around the globe; typically the address is associated with the closest measurement node.  This is a more accurate method, but requires running many well-connected nodes and sending a lot of internet traffic to, at a minimum, each /24 on the internet.

Answer (score -2):

All IP address from the Google Cloud will always originate to US, particularly Mountain View City, because it is linked to Google HQ which is located there. I would like you to know that all data and hardware for your instance are located on specific data centers across the globe, depending on the location that you have selected. You may refer to this link [1] for reference. However, Google Public DNS uses the anycast routing to direct the packets to the closest DNS server geographically, so if you are assigning an IP address for any instance, Google's network will be aware that the IP address is on that zone, even if the IP address was originally from Mountain View, California. See this link [2] [3] for a detailed explanation. The reason that you see your instance's IP address originate from US is because the entire IP block is owned by Google and the ARIN information lists the address for the entire block to Google's HQ in Mountain View.

[1] https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gce-discussion/ip$20in$20us%7Csort:relevance/gce-discussion/otD1c6E-wWI/cvEDCUAlBAAJ 
[2] [Why do Google Cloud Platform static IP addresses list Mountain View, CA in reverse lookup regardless of region assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988170/why-do-google-cloud-platform-static-ip-addresses-list-mountain-view-ca-in-rever) 
[3] https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gce-discussion/us$20ip%7Csort:relevance/gce-discussion/RjzyHRBRujg/Fd21YlmOpzEJ