# Google Cloud VM Locations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I've set up a Google Compute Engine VM in australia-southeast1-a, but the IP address indicated the server was in China.  I then assigned a static IP from Sydney as well but the IP address I received indicates California?!  Any idea how I can rectify?

[Screenshot from Google Cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ViPC.png)

[IP location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfbKB.png)

Comment: posible repeat question. [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988170/why-do-google-cloud-platform-static-ip-addresses-list-mountain-view-ca-in-rever) help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do Google Cloud Platform static IP addresses list Mountain View, CA in reverse lookup regardless of region assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988170/why-do-google-cloud-platform-static-ip-addresses-list-mountain-view-ca-in-rever)