# Why my public IP is from USA and my VM is located in southamerica-east1-a?

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine

Thanks in advance for all replies.
I have created an instance to run a system for VoIP. The instance has been created according to Google instructions and an IP public has been set to work with this instance.
The IP address is 35.199.100.126 and the instance is located in southamerica-east1-a.
Why my IP public address is shown in California - USA?
I am having some troubles regarding latency. Should not it be an IP from São Paulo?

Best regards.

Enio Eltz Filho.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do Google Cloud Platform static IP addresses list Mountain View, CA in reverse lookup regardless of region assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988170/why-do-google-cloud-platform-static-ip-addresses-list-mountain-view-ca-in-rever)

Answer (score 0):

Google does not give you a public IP for your machine as we normally see. Normally an interface in your machine has an IP assigned to it. But at GCP, the public facing "interface" is not located in your VM, but the systems is rather a tragic forwarding to your VM. In your case, the IP that lives in your local (GCP) network is the one in south america.

The above should address your question, but to address your issue, please check if the private IP location is the real issue, as they as the internal communication is extremely fast. After that, please evaluate you network tier in your GCP structure, as VOIP is an extremely sensitive systems with regards to speed.

Comment: You are welcome. Welcome to our community btw. Please accept or upvote the answer when you see fit and the information helps you. This will help the next person with the same doudt to locate useful information.