# Europe regions still have US IP address, can I change this?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-networking

I'm using Betfair's (sport betting) API and have put together some cloud functions to be triggered on certain events.

However, it seems that despite choosing a european region, in which it's legal to gamble online, the IP address of the server running the functions is in the US, so Betfair block any API request coming from the cloud function.

Is there any way I can guarantee that it comes from a european IP?

I did see an old post regarding this but hoping there's now an actual solution to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google’s IP addresses registered to the HQ in Mountain View. The SWIP record / WHOIS entry denotes only the administrative ownership of an IP address. Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988170/why-do-google-cloud-platform-static-ip-addresses-list-mountain-view-ca-in-rever for detail explanation if you have not visited before. 

So, you could check with Betfair on how they are determining IP address location and explain them the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do Google Cloud Platform static IP addresses list Mountain View, CA in reverse lookup regardless of region assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988170/why-do-google-cloud-platform-static-ip-addresses-list-mountain-view-ca-in-rever)

Answer (score 1):

cloud functions is a serverless service, to ensure that the outgoing IP is European you need to create a NAT in the European region, assign a /28 subnet and create a Serverless VPC Connector attached to that same subnet. Remember to configure cloud functions so that all egress requests go through the VPC Connector.