# Cloud Run: Region should be europe, but requests come from US

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm a little bit confused. All our Cloud Run instances are located in EU regions. But if I block US traffic on CloudFlare, they loose access too. Or in other words, their requests come from US addresses even if they should be located in EU regions.

Did I do some misconfiguration? Can I do anything to fix this issue? Our whole infrastructure is on GCP and we set EU regions on all resources. I expected everything to be located in the EU, but it seems like I was wrong.

Comment: Blocking traffic by region is not a good strategy and is easily defeated. Most geolocation services use the registered business address and not the actual location that traffic originates from. Consider using Google load balancers instead of Cloudflare as it supports an optional header that provides more accurate geolocation information due to the massive number of Google "points of presence" POPs.

Comment: I totally agree with you @JohnHanley for us it is more about data protection purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine! No worries! The only issue is that Google is a US corporate!

Indeed, when Google bought the IP blocks, it referenced its headquarter address as the IP origin.

Therefore, when you use a Google Cloud IP, the IP is listed as coming from the US.

Traffic origin is not really reliable and trustable, prefer authenticated traffic.

Answer (score 2):

All External IP addresses provided by GCP will show located in Mountain View Google headquarters because it was using SWIP database, this was also discussed and gave a detailed description about this concern on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988170/why-do-google-cloud-platform-static-ip-addresses-list-mountain-view-ca-in-rever?answertab=votes#tab-top) here in stackoverflow.